# preg_match trailing slash in url

Tags: regex, preg-match

I want to make sure that a visitor is exactly at the homepage of the site.
Is this correct to match if the url is:

- www.site.com
- www.site.com/
- www.site.com/index.php

  ```
  preg_match("/^(www.)?(".$host.")(\/)?(index.php)?$/", $url, $matches)
  ```

It doesn't seem too formally correct to separate the last two matches like this, but it works
Plus is there any browser that doesn't "redirect" a www.site.com to www.site.com/?

Comment: Looks good. 
You do a lot of capture groups with `()`. You can get rid of the groups completely I think. But if you are worried, have you considered making them non-capture groups `(?:)` (as per Perl regex anyways)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close. I would go with this instead:

```
preg_match("/^(?:www\.)?(?:".$host.")(?:\/(?:index\.php)?)?(?:\?.*)?$/", $url, $matches)
```

The differences here are:

- Escaping `.` characters meant as literal dots (a dot normally means "any character except `\n` or `\r`" in regular expressions).
- Requiring a `/` before `index.php`, if `index.php` is present.
- Optionally allowing GET parameters (the `\?.*` part).
- Non-capturing groups, since you don't seem interested in going through the captures.

Other than that, it looks good to me.